# Java Generate String Unique to Application Build

Tags: java, security, signing

As part of my application's security it generates signed JWT tokens. I'm curious about the feasibility of incorporating a kind of automatic of versioning in the signature, to invalidate old tokens created by previous versions of the application (despite other checks such as expiration date). I could accomplish this via some sort of version property in a configuration file, but I'm afraid it that updating it would be forgotten. I couldn't find anything on this, I think I must be using the wrong terms to describe what I'm trying to do.

Is there a simple way, to get a value uniquely tied the current build/version/etc?

Comment: Use a hash of your JAR?

Comment: Depends how you’re building your application.  Your build could write the current revision to a text file and bundle that.  Or, Ant has a [BuildNumber task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html).

Comment: Can an application scan its own JAR at runtime? Hopefully, would avoid putting a dependency on the build script for application functionality. Maybe what I'm looking for doesn't exist. There is no built in Java API call that retrieves a value that would only change between builds (but remains same in different environments, etc).